# Creating an own theme for Magento

Tags: html, css, magento, themes, magento-1.7

I cannot seem to find up to date tutorials for creating own themes from scratch for the current release of Magento, can anyone point me to one? The most comprehensive I know which but is a little out of date is [this](http://zaclee.net/magento/make-magento-1-6-theme-from-scratch)

Or could anyone give me a short step by step crash course on building one? I have some knowledge about the theme system of Magento by now.

Comment: At the magento wiki there's a clear tutorial. But I think that is not quite what you want. http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/working-with-magento-themes

Comment: Try http://www.gravitywell.co.uk/blog/post/magento-creating-your-own-design-package-with-theme-variants

Comment: You can go through MagentoDesignGuide.pdf too